# How to change the size of smartdiagram circle and rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have this diagram. How can I change the size of the circle and the triangle so that the text stay in one line?

```
\smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{  
 {Unsharp boundary,{ Vague concepts lack sharp boundary}},  
 {Borderline cases, {Vague concepts have borderline cases}},  
 {Tolerance, {Vague concepts are tolerant to very small changes}},  
 {Sorites susceptability, {Vague concepts raise Sorites paradoxs}},  
 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the circles big enough to show the text without linebreaks they will vertically overlap because there isn't enough vertical space on a frame (or you'll need to use such a tiny font that your audience will need spectacles...).

Maybe as a compromise: make them a big bigger, the font a bit smaller and the text will fit in two lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\smartdiagramset{
  description text width=7cm,
  description font=\footnotesize,
  description title text width=1.2cm,
  description title font=\tiny,
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{  
   {Unsharp boundary,{ Vague concepts lack sharp boundary}},  
   {Borderline cases, {Vague concepts have borderline cases}},  
   {Tolerance, {Vague concepts are tolerant to very small changes}},  
   {Sorites susceptability, {Vague concepts raise Sorites paradoxs},},
   }  
  
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]